# How do I multiply the values in two array list, in order to find the total?

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the total cost of items in the users cart. My approach to this is to store the item cost as well as the quantity in an `ArrayList` and then multiply the value then add it. For example this is my `ArrayList`. I would like to do

```
2.00 * 5.00 + 3.00 * 6.00 + 4.00 * 7.00 + 5.00 * 8.00
```

What I have done so far multiplies the first number in the `ArrayList` by every item in the `ArrayList`. This is not what I am trying to do. Can someone help with this?

```
quaninityArrayList [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
priceArraListy[5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
```

---

```
ArrayList<Double>  priceArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double>  quantitiyArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

quantitiyArrayList.add(2.00);
quantitiyArrayList.add(3.00);
quantitiyArrayList.add(4.00);
quantitiyArrayList.add(5.00);

priceArrayList.add(5.00 );
priceArrayList.add(6.00 );
priceArrayList.add(7.00 );
priceArrayList.add(8.00 );

for(int i = 0; i<quantitiyArrayList.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j< priceArrayList.size(); j++){
              System.out.println(quantitiyArrayList.get(i)*priceArrayList.get(j));
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be helpful to have some code to help fix.

Comment: This sounds like homework. Do you know how to use a loop? Do you know how to get values from a list?  This is pretty basic so perhaps you should discuss this with your instructor.

Comment: Add two other System.out.println to see the values of i and j for each iteration. This will help you to understande what is going wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
 //do calculations.
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < quantityArrayDouble.length; i++) {
            sum += quantityArrayDouble[i] * priceArrayDouble[i];
        }
        Log.i("sum", sum + "");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below (assuming both the array lists has same no of elements):

```
StringBuilder strinBuilder = new StringBuilder();
double total = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < quantitiyArrayList.size(); i++) {
        try {
            strinBuilder.append(quantitiyArrayList.get(i) + " * " + priceArrayList.get(i) + " + ");

            total = total + (quantitiyArrayList.get(i) * priceArrayList.get(i));
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            total = total + 0.0;
        }
}
CharSequence output = "(" + strinBuilder.toString().subSequence(0, strinBuilder.toString().length() - 3) + ") = " + total;
System.out.println(output);
System.out.println("Total is: " + total);
```

Comment: If they are not the same length, you could catch the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` inside the loop and add `0.0` to `total`.